# Is it possible to use lookup and currency fields in a Salesforce skinny table?

Tags: currency, lookup-field, skinny-table

I want to create a skinny table to improve reports performance. However, some of the most used fields in the reports are lookups and currency fields. In Salesforce documentation, I didn't see these field data types listed in the supported data types for skinny tables.
Is there a way to include these fields in a skinny table? Any workaround?

Comment: Welcome to SFSE!. Please see [ask] on getting the most from the community.

Answer (score 1):

Answer is No, As per [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_large_data_volumes_bp.meta/salesforce_large_data_volumes_bp/ldv_deployments_infrastructure_skinny_tables.htm) only below fields can contain skinny table.

[image]

Workaround would be add more filter and make selective queries.